# Why does Python for .NET hold the Global Interpreter Lock during constructor but not method calls?

Tags: c#, python, multithreading, python.net, pythonnet

I have several classes written in C# that I want to consume from an application written in Python using Python for .NET.

Having previously done something similar using Python4Delphi and Python's C API I know how crucial it is to hold the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) for everything that interacts with Python, while releasing it during long-running operations so other Python threads may run.

For acquiring the GIL, Python for .NET comes with the handy `Py.GIL()` utility and I wrote `NoGil` to make it just as easy to release the GIL.

I had assumed that whenever Python code called the C# code, the GIL was held for the duration of the call. It seems, though, that the GIL is not held during method calls, while it is held during a constructor call, as illustrated by the example below.

Here is the C# class and my `NoGil` utility class with some logging. For simplicity I did not implement the Disposable pattern in full.

```
using Python.Runtime;
using System;

namespace PythonNet
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public Class1()
        {
            using (new NoGil("constructor"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("executing constructor");
            }
        }

        public void Method()
        {
            using (new NoGil("method"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("executing method");
            }
        }
    }

    public class NoGil: IDisposable
    {
        private string _message;
        private IntPtr _state = IntPtr.Zero;

        public NoGil(string message)
        {
            _message = message;
            Console.WriteLine("Before calling BeginAllowThreads from " + message);
            _state = PythonEngine.BeginAllowThreads();
            Console.WriteLine("After calling BeginAllowThreads from " + _message);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (_state == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("B_state == IntPtr.Zero in " + _message);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Before calling EndAllowThreads from " + _message);
                PythonEngine.EndAllowThreads(_state);
                Console.WriteLine("After calling EndAllowThreads from " + _message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is used from Python (after having installed the pythonnet package via pip) like this:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("PythonNet.dll")
from PythonNet import Class1
c = Class1()
c.Method()
```

The output is

```
Before calling BeginAllowThreads from constructor
After calling BeginAllowThreads from constructor
executing constructor
Before calling EndAllowThreads from constructor
After calling EndAllowThreads from constructor
Before calling BeginAllowThreads from method
Fatal Python error: PyEval_SaveThread: NULL tstate

Current thread 0x0000124c (most recent call first):
  File "test.py", line 5 in <module>
```

I tried this with Python 2.7 and 3.6 (both 64 bit), the latest version 2.3.0 of Python for .NET and both .NET 4.0 and 4.6.1 as my target framework.

**Questions:**

1. Is this expected behavior in Python for .NET or should I file a bug?
2. If it is expected, what exactly are the situations where I can assume that the GIL is being held when calling .NET code? I did not find any documentation on this.
3. Or should I never assume anything about the GIL and always acquire it when necessary (i.e. when calling into Python code via delegates)? Then how do I make sure I don't hold it during a lengthy non-Python operation?

Comment: Can you repost the output, code-formatted instead of quote-formatted, so we can be sure of *exactly* what the code produced?

Comment: [It looks like pythonnet *does* auto-release the GIL for method calls](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/blob/8f258acbf6a605ada4045391dc14f21bfc79fda6/src/runtime/methodbinder.cs#L514), for some reason.

Comment: Reformatted the output. Thanks for the link. Looks like unless a method is marked with the `[ForbidPythonThreads]` attribute (which unfortunately is internal), the GIL will be released before the call. Not so for constructors, however.

Comment: Allow threads and acquire GIL are a bit different, e.g. see this PR discussion: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/pull/419